# Codeigniter 4 Model with different Database Connection

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am using the Models of Codeigniter 4 and I have many different databases.
For my problem I'm taking just 2:

- mainDB (application-stuff)
- clientDB (client-stuff)

Every client gets his own database.

Now I have several models for every table in my system. But some models should not only look on their tables, they should automatically switch Database. For example the clientUsersModel.

So if I have something like this:

```
$this->clientUsersModel()->findAll();
// I have all my models stored in a object, so I can access them easy in every Controller without manually initiating them JFI
```

... it should automatically switch (setDatabase) the database to the client-database.

I tried the `__call()` function, so when a function inside the model gets called I can call another function for a db-check, but it only get's called, when a function is not existing.

Is there another way to do so?

My target is:

Controller->ClientModel->function() (switches to ClientDB to do operative things)
Controller->NormalModel->function() (swtiches back to mainDB to do operative things)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple database, edit Config\Database and add new Connection
[Database-CI4_COnfiguration](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/configuration.html)

, then connect to new Database [Database-CI4-Connection](https://$db1%20=%20%5CConfig%5CDatabase::connect(%27group_one%27);%20$db2%20=%20%5CConfig%5CDatabase::connect(%27group_two%27);)